# Multiple ListViews: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I know, that this question has already been answered, and I also know the solution to the simple problem. Just add `android:id="@android:id/list"` to the ListView. But the problem I'm having is a bit different. My problem differns in the following ways:

1: I'm using a Fragment
2: I want to use multiple ListViews
3: I have Custom Array Adapters

I have a `LinearLayout` that contains two other `LinearLayout`. Each of them holding another `ListView`. So simply, I want two different `ListViews` in my Layout. The problem now, is that I want them both to work. How would I do that?

```
//LinearLayoutStart
//Some code
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_openGames"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Offene Spiele"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_openGames"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_openChallenges"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Offene Herausforderungen"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge">
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_openChallenges"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>    
//LinearLayoutEnd
```

So, now in my Java Code I do the following:

```
private ChallengeListAdapter adapterListChallenges;
private ArrayList<Challenge> arrayListChallenges = new ArrayList<Challenge>();
private GameListAdapter adapterListGames;
private ArrayList<Game> arrayListGames = new ArrayList<Game>();
private ListView lvOpenGames;
private ListView lvOpenChallenges;

lvOpenChallenges        = ( ListView ) view.findViewById ( R.id.lv_openChallenges );
lvOpenGames             = ( ListView ) view.findViewById ( R.id.lv_openGames );
adapterListChallenges   = new ChallengeListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), arrayListChallenges);
adapterListGames        = new GameListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), arrayListGames);
lvOpenChallenges.setAdapter ( adapterListChallenges );
lvOpenGames     .setAdapter ( adapterListGames);
```

When I'm only using one `ListView` and one adapter it works fine, since I can just give one of the `ListView`s the id `android:list`, and then just call `setListAdapter`. But now, I'm also in a fragment. So how exactly would I go with this?

Comment: But what's exactly the problem you have? What did you try? Are you using a Fragment or a ListFragment?

Comment: I'm using a `ListFragment`. The problem is, that I don't know how to handle it, when I have two `ListView`s. I know, how to handle this error, when I have only one `ListView`, but how do I do it, when I have two? I mean, when I call `setListAdapter` I can't really tell the App which of the two `ListView`s to use, right?

Comment: You have to use a Fragment, not a ListFragment so you can manage all the listviews you want separately. ListFragment is a helpful class that does a bit of work for you but it needs just one listview in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ListFragment/ListActivity are just convenience classes that let you slightly more easily access your list view if you have only one of them (and call it `@android:id/list`). They also provide automatic behavior where an alternate view `@android:id/empty` will be shown instead of the list view if it's empty (if you choose to include that in your layout).

When you have more than one, you can use a regular Fragment or Activity and don't call any of your list views `@android:id/list`. They should have different IDs.

Instead, keep a member reference to each ListView and Adapter. You will need a separate adapter for each ListView.  When you want to set a list adapter on a list view, call directly into the list view, for example: `mListView1.setAdapter(mListAdapter1);`.

Comment: So this means, I would just extend `Fragment` instead of `ListFragment` and then implement `OnItemClickListener` and make the `OnItemClickListener` handle the rest?

Comment: Yes, and you can filter what you do in `onItemClick` by casting `parent` to ListView and seeing if it `==` one of your two member variables for list views. Or, just instantiate a couple of OnItemClickListeners as anonymous classes.

Comment: Thanks! :) Very helpful. And I like that you didn't write much code in your answer. This way I could try it out myself and understand it more